# What do Latter Day Saints believe happens to persons who have rejected Christ Jesus?

Tags: lds, hell, afterlife

The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter Day Saints says this in their third article of faith:

> 3. We believe that through the Atonement of Christ, all mankind may be saved, by obedience to the laws and ordinances of the Gospel.  http://www.mormon.org.uk/beliefs/articles-of-faith

I also found this statement while I was doing research into the subject:

> As spirits, we will have an interim judgment which will determine whether our spirits go to Paradise (where the Savior went when his body was in the tomb) or to the Spirit Prison called Hell.

***Is this Spirit Prison called Hell a place of eternal torment, or do those who have rejected Christ Jesus get a second chance to be saved?***

On the subject of unrepentant sinners and the Telestial Kingdom, I found this quote:

> The Telestial Kingdom will be populated with the unrepentant sinners who, in spite of the fact that they did ultimately acknowledge Jesus to be the Christ, refused to accept His teachings or His atoning sacrifice on their behalf. They were too proud or too rebellious to care to commit themselves to Him in any way, and were willing to accept the consequences for their refusal. They will spend eternity as “servants of the Most High but where God and Christ dwell they cannot come…” Doctrine & Covenants 76:112.

I would also be interested to find out if the beliefs of Latter Day Saints on this subject have any basis in the words of Jesus as recorded in the New Testament.

Comment: Re the sub-question at the end, are you looking only for words of Jesus or do you consider New Testament words of Jesus or the apostles to be in scope?

Comment: My question is addressed to LDS so I expect answers that will quote from official LDS sources.  However, it would be absolutely wonderful if LDS answers could quote from the New Testament in support of their beliefs.  I'm one of those pesky Protestants who hold to the Bible as God's holy and inspired word, and I believe what Jesus said.

Comment: Got it, thanks--just wanted to confirm words of Paul or Peter fit what you were looking for.

Comment: The words of Paul and Peter are also inspired by God and more than acceptable. Thank you.

Comment: Re *"Christ Jesus"*: Shouldn't it be *"[Jesus Christ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Jesus_Christ#Proper_noun)"*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen  The difference between Jesus Christ and Christ Jesus is subtle and in most contexts insignificant. Placing the human name first puts a slight emphasis on the Lord’s humanity; placing the divine title first puts a slight emphasis on the Lord’s deity. Either way, Jesus is the Christ, the Messiah, the Chosen One of God.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**All mankind may be saved**

The word to emphasize (relative to the OP’s question) from the third article of faith is *may*. This passage does not teach universalism, but rather, that the full, salvific effects of Jesus’ atoning sacrifice are *available* to everyone. The Gospel of Jesus Christ then, to a Latter-day Saint, describes the atoning sacrifice of Jesus Christ and how we access its power.  One prominent example comes from Alma 12:15

> that all his judgments are just; that he is just in all his works, and
> that he is merciful unto the children of men, and that he has all
> power to save every man that believeth on his name and bringeth forth
> fruit meet for repentance.

Can Christ save them? Absolutely.

Will He force salvation upon them? No.

A more extended treatment of *what is the Gospel of Jesus Christ* can be found in [3 Nephi chapter 27](https://abn.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/bofm/3-ne/27?lang=eng), see verses 13-22.

I won’t segue into a lengthy discussion about the terminology “saved” and “grace”, but if any are interested, my thoughts are available in [this video](https://youtu.be/Ld9C0Px0FLw). For purposes of this question, suffice it to say:

- “Salvation”, in the most complete sense of the word, describes the
  effect of fully participating in God’s plan of salvation
- “Grace” is Divine enabling power that is offered as a gift by God and
  can only be *fully* accessed through covenants with God.

--

**The Spirit World**

Latter-day Saints believe that between death and the resurrection, human spirits inhabit the spirit world. That there are differing statuses within the spirit world is described by Alma 40:

> 11 Now, concerning the state of the soul between death and the
> resurrection—Behold, it has been made known unto me by an angel, that
> the spirits of all men, as soon as they are departed from this mortal
> body, yea, the spirits of all men, whether they be good or evil, are
> taken home to that God who gave them life.
>
> 12 And then shall it come to pass, that the spirits of those who are
> righteous are received into a state of happiness, which is called
> paradise, a state of rest, a state of peace, where they shall rest
> from all their troubles and from all care, and sorrow.
>
> 13 And then shall it come to pass, that the spirits of the wicked,
> yea, who are evil—for behold, they have no part nor portion of the
> Spirit of the Lord; for behold, they chose evil works rather than
> good; therefore the spirit of the devil did enter into them, and take
> possession of their house—and these shall be cast out into outer
> darkness; there shall be weeping, and wailing, and gnashing of teeth,
> and this because of their own iniquity, being led captive by the will
> of the devil.
>
> 14 Now this is the state of the souls of the wicked, yea, in darkness,
> and a state of awful, fearful looking for the fiery indignation of the
> wrath of God upon them; thus they remain in this state, as well as the
> righteous in paradise, until the time of their resurrection.

These divisions are usually referred to colloquially as “paradise” and “spirit prison”, but, as already noted by depperm, “hell” is often used to describe “spirit prison”.

As in the Bible, hell can be used to refer to the place where the wicked are prior to the resurrection (see Revelation 20:12). Hell is also very often used colloquially to refer to the lake of fire after the resurrection and judgement (see Revelation 20:15).

Disambiguation of hell:

- Spirit prison--the abode of the spirits who are not in paradise,
  while awaiting the resurrection
- Outer Darkness--the ultimate fate of Satan and his angels, and the
  sons of perdition (those who do not receive a kingdom of glory, see
  below)

That the Gospel of Jesus is taught to spirits in spirit prison is taught in great detail in [Doctrine & Covenants 138](https://abn.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/138?lang=eng)  ; I’ll cite just a fraction of it here:

> 31 And the chosen messengers [in the spirit world] went forth to
> declare the acceptable day of the Lord and proclaim liberty to the
> captives who were bound, even unto all who would repent of their sins
> and receive the gospel.
>
> 32 Thus was the gospel preached to those who had died in their sins,
> without a knowledge of the truth, or in transgression, having rejected
> the prophets.
>
> 33 These were taught faith in God, repentance from sin, vicarious
> baptism for the remission of sins, the gift of the Holy Ghost by the
> laying on of hands,

(vicarious baptism because they no longer have a body and someone with a body performs the ordinance on their behalf--more details in my post [here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/58700/39862) - note that Latter-day Saints practice vicarious ordinances because the practice was revealed to the prophet Joseph Smith, not based simply on a deduction from 1 Cor. 15:29)

Notice that there are 2 reasons given:

- To provide the gospel message to those died without a knowledge of
  the truth--Latter-day Saints believe that the billions of people who
  have died without ever hearing the name of Jesus Christ, let alone
  learned His gospel, will have that opportunity in the spirit world
- To provide the gospel message to those who rejected the prophets

It’s this latter point upon which many get hung up. Does this mean there is no penalty to them for having rejected the prophets? Does this mean we might as well eat, drink, and be merry, party in this life, and then wait and accept the gospel in the spirit world? Definitely not.

I’ll establish this two ways:

First, as taught by Amulek:

> 30 And now, my brethren, I would that, after ye have received so many
> witnesses, seeing that the holy scriptures testify of these things, ye
> come forth and bring fruit unto repentance.
>
> 31 Yea, I would that ye would come forth and harden not your hearts
> any longer; for behold, now is the time and the day of your salvation;
> and therefore, if ye will repent and harden not your hearts,
> immediately shall the great plan of redemption be brought about unto
> you.
>
> 32 For behold, this life is the time for men to prepare to meet God;
> yea, behold the day of this life is the day for men to perform their
> labors.
>
> 33 And now, as I said unto you before, as ye have had so many
> witnesses, therefore, I beseech of you that ye do not procrastinate
> the day of your repentance until the end; for after this day of life,
> which is given us to prepare for eternity, behold, if we do not
> improve our time while in this life, then cometh the night of darkness
> wherein there can be no labor performed.
>
> 34 Ye cannot say, when ye are brought to that awful crisis, that I
> will repent, that I will return to my God. Nay, ye cannot say this;
> for that same spirit which doth possess your bodies at the time that
> ye go out of this life, that same spirit will have power to possess
> your body in that eternal world.

We will be the same people then as now--if we have wasted away the talents and opportunities God has given us in this life, we will be held accountable for that in the next. We will not magically be transformed into someone else, nor will our desires be different. We will have already been given a time of probation (Notice also that Amulek is speaking to people who have indeed had the gospel taught to them in this life).

For those who did not have those opportunities in this life, was their mortal life a waste? No--see below.

Second, God’s plan is not about filling out a checklist, it is about *becoming*. To the extent that God has given “checklists”, the checklists exist for the purpose of aiding our process of becoming. To borrow a phrase, the checklists were created for man and not man for the checklists.

God’s plan is a plan about becoming. If we use whatever portion of God’s light we are given in this life to progress, we will continue in that direction in the next life. If we reject God’s light, we may find eternally too late that we have lost opportunities that will not return, and we will limit our eternal potential.

We will be held accountable for what we know and the opportunities we’ve been given:

> 47 And that servant, which knew his lord’s will, and prepared not
> himself, neither did according to his will, shall be beaten with many
> stripes.
>
> 48 But he that knew not, and did commit things worthy of stripes,
> shall be beaten with few stripes. For unto whomsoever much is given,
> of him shall be much required: and to whom men have committed much, of
> him they will ask the more. (Luke 12:47-48)

As church President Russell M. Nelson has taught:

> [I] question the efficacy of proxy temple work for a man who had the
> opportunity to be baptized in this life—to be ordained to the
> priesthood and receive temple blessings while here in mortality—but
> who made the conscious decision to reject that course. (see [here](https://abn.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/general-conference/2019/04/46nelson?lang=eng))

Only God can decide what constitutes adequate opportunity to accept or reject the fullness of the gospel. That all will be given a first chance to accept the gospel is clearly taught. That all will be granted a second chance is not--doesn’t sound like a gamble worth taking.

--

**Eternal torment**

That unrepentant sin will result in suffering is clearly established in [Doctrine & Covenants 19](https://abn.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/19?lang=eng):15-19.

Eternal can refer to something that does not end--such as the permanence of the anguish associated with outer darkness.

Eternal is also a name for Christ, and can refer to something given by Him (see Doctrine & Covenants 19: 9-12).

The anguish *in spirit prison* is “eternal punishment” in that it is “God’s punishment”; it is not eternal in the sense that it lasts forever.

Spirit prison is a temporary abode. Will there be anguish after the spirit world, after resurrection & judgement? In outer darkness, clearly yes (see Doctrine & Covenants 76:32-38). Elsewhere?  See below.

--

**Kingdoms of glory**

Latter-day Saints believe that after judgement there is more than just heaven and hell. We believe in kingdoms of glory: Celestial, Terrestrial, and Telestial. Since these details are not the focus of the OP, and I’ve already written way too much, I’ll refer the reader to [Doctrine & Covenants 76](https://abn.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/76?lang=eng) for the details of each. [This video](https://youtu.be/Ld9C0Px0FLw) on my channel provides some commentary as well.

A quick summary is that only celestial glory constitutes “eternal life”, but that God has prepared for all whatever portion of glory they are prepared to receive.

I have to imagine that in the Terrestrial & Telestial kingdoms there is some sort of anguish associated with falling short of one’s potential.

--

**Sources**

Because The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints accepts the Bible, the Book of Mormon, the Doctrine & Covenants, and the Pearl of Great Price as inspired, canonical scripture, members generally feel no obligation to prove a doctrinal position using only just one of the four. There are only a handful of passages repeated in all four, and, in fact, there are things we believe that are taught in the Bible but are not taught in the Book of Mormon!

From a Latter-day Saint perspective, this would be akin to asking Protestants to prove all doctrinal positions using only the four Gospels.

My own position is that the plan of salvation taught by the church is consistent with the Bible, but not proven by the Bible (“prove” is a strong word--if the Bible deductively proved one and only one very precise theology, we would expect only one doctrine to be accepted by those who believe the Bible. The existence of multiple Bible-based theologies demonstrates it is possible to interpret Biblical passages in more than one way).

All Biblical passages I will cite below have been interpreted by various groups in more than one way. To a Latter-day Saint, modern revelation casts a clarifying light on ancient scripture, it does not replace ancient scripture.

Evidence of sincerity--here I cannot speak for other Latter-day Saints, just for myself, but if anyone doubts my love for the Bible, please visit my [YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCyzcAPfVA5-K7EMym8Fd-Fw), approximately half of which is dedicated to demonstrating the reliability and tremendous worth of the four Gospels.

All of that said, I do claim that the doctrinal views above are consistent with the Bible, and most of them are taught in the Bible. I should also point out that among the quotes in the OP, only the first one and the last 14 words of the third one come from scripture.

Biblical references (I’ll cite one for each topic, more available upon request):

*All mankind **may** be saved*

> And he is the propitiation for our sins: and not for ours only, but
> also for the sins of the whole world. (1 John 2:2)

*Not all mankind **will** be saved:*

> And whosoever was not found written in the book of life was cast into
> the lake of fire. (Revelation 20:15)

*Spirit World prior to the resurrection*

> 22 And it came to pass, that the beggar died, and was carried by the
> angels into Abraham’s bosom: the rich man also died, and was buried;
>
> 23 And in hell he lift up his eyes, being in torments, and seeth
> Abraham afar off, and Lazarus in his bosom. (Luke 16:22-23)

Note that the Greek word rendered “hell” here is Hades, which in scripture is the Greek equivalent of the Hebrew Sheol. To Jews, Sheol described the abode of spirits prior to the resurrection. For a much more detailed discussion of the Biblical meanings of “hell”, see my post on Hermneutics [here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/59907/39862).

Note also that Sheol was generally thought of as existing in two “levels”, one for the righteous and one for the wicked.

*Gospel preached to the dead*

> 18 For Christ also hath once suffered for sins, the just for the
> unjust, that he might bring us to God, being put to death in the
> flesh, but quickened by the Spirit:
>
> 19 By which also he went and
> preached unto the spirits in prison;
>
> 20 Which sometime were
> disobedient, when once the longsuffering of God waited in the days of
> Noah, while the ark was a preparing, wherein few, that is, eight souls
> were saved by water. (1 Peter 3:18-20)

*Kingdoms of glory*

> There is one glory of the sun, and another glory of the moon, and
> another glory of the stars: for one star differeth from another star
> in glory. (1 Corinthians 15:41)

See also Luke 12:47-48 cited above.

--

**Conclusion**

This is a Latter-day Saint perspective--I say this as someone who believes on separate grounds that the fulness of the Gospel of Jesus Christ was restored through a prophet in modern times. I wouldn’t expect anyone who does not hold this premise to agree with what I say next.

I do not claim that the doctrines I have outlined are proven by the Bible, but rather that they are in the Bible--and that through modern revelation their meaning is reinforced and made clear.

---

Disclaimer: my comments are the product of my own study and do not constitute official statements by The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints

Comment: @FredLarson sure did! Thanks for catching the typo; I updated the post.

Comment: Although I do not accept the Book of Mormon, and I never visit You Tube chanels, I found the link to Doctrines and Covenants informative.

Answer (score 4):

The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints believe in the [plan of salvation](https://abn.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/true-to-the-faith/plan-of-salvation?lang=eng), which addresses several of the OPs questions.

> Is this Spirit Prison called Hell a place of eternal torment, or do those who have rejected Christ Jesus get a second chance to be saved?

It depends, the LDS have two definitions of hell but the spirit prison definition is not eternal. From guide to scriptures, [hell](https://abn.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/gs/hell?lang=eng)

> Latter-day revelation speaks of **hell in at least two senses**. **First, it is the temporary abode in the spirit world for those who were disobedient in mortality. In this sense, hell has an end.** The spirits there will be taught the gospel, and sometime following their repentance they will be resurrected to a degree of glory of which they are worthy. Those who will not repent, but are nevertheless not sons of perdition, will remain in hell throughout the Millennium. After these thousand years of torment, they will be resurrected to a telestial glory (D&C 76:81–86; 88:100–101).

> **Second, it is the permanent location of those who are not redeemed by the Atonement of Jesus Christ. In this sense, hell is permanent.** It is for those who are found “filthy still” (D&C 88:35, 102). This is the place where Satan, his angels, and the sons of perdition—those who have denied the Son after the Father has revealed Him—will dwell eternally

Scriptural basis for kingdoms of heaven solely in the New Testament are limited but they include:

- [Matthew 13:43](https://abn.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/nt/matt/13.43?lang=eng#43?lang=eng) (celestial glory)

> 43 Then shall the righteous shine forth as the **sun in the kingdom of their Father**. Who hath ears to hear, let him hear.

- [John 14:2](https://abn.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/nt/john/14.2?lang=eng#p2#2) (degrees of glory)

> 2 In my Father’s house are **many mansions**: if it were not so, I would have told you. I go to prepare a place for you.

- [1 Corinthians 15:40-42](https://abn.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/nt/1-cor/15.40-42?lang=eng#p40#40) (degrees of glory)

> 40 There are also **celestial bodies, and bodies terrestrial: but the glory of the celestial is one, and the glory of the terrestrial is another**.

> 41 There is one **glory of the sun, and another glory of the moon, and another glory of the stars**: for one star differeth from another star in glory.

> 42 So also is the resurrection of the dead. It is sown in corruption; it is raised in incorruption:

- [2 Corinthians 12:2](https://abn.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/nt/2-cor/12.2?lang=eng#2?lang=eng) (celestial glory)

> 2 I knew a man in Christ above fourteen years ago, (whether in the body, I cannot tell; or whether out of the body, I cannot tell: God knoweth;) such an one caught up to the **third heaven.**

Other scriptures/details about kingdoms of glory can be found in [True to the Faith: Kingdoms of Glory](https://abn.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/true-to-the-faith/kingdoms-of-glory?lang=eng)

<sub>all emphasis added by me</sub>

Comment: Useful information in the links you provided. Thanks.